# jQuery File Upload - Image preview links

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, hyperlink, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the jQuery File Upload. Everything works well during the upload process (files are getting uploaded well, in a folder I chose on my server).

But then, when images are uploaded, I should see them in a `<a>` in the `<span class="preview">` that is generated by the `<script id="template-download">` (original script from demo file).

In place, I get an broken link image and a "404 (not found)" in the console. Indeed when I check where It's looking for the image I have something like :

```
href="/home/domaindb/domain.fr/uploads/image.png"
```

Whereas it should be something like :

```
href="/uploads/image.png"
```

So, how can I change the way href links are created ? When I'm looking directly in the `<script id="template-download">` on my upload page, there is the `<a href="{%=file.url%}">` but I guess there's nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, In the end I found a solution.

In the UploadHandler.php there is the setting `'download_via_php' => false` by default. I set it to `'download_via_php' => 1` to allow download via readfile method through PHP.

Now, href links look like this :

```
href="http://domain.fr/jquery-fu/server/php/index.php?file=IM1.png&download=1"
```

I suppose this is more secure as it doesn't show the real path of the file on the server (if someone can confirm...).